# How can I generate another entry widget when I press enter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am making a tournament software and I want to make it so when I press enter, another entry widget appears, this is my code

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import sys
master = Tk()
master.title('Tournament Software')
master.geometry("800x800")
master.configure(background="black")
def end():
    master.destroy()
def click1():
    master.destroy()
    master1 = Tk()
    master1.title("Tournament Software")
    master1.geometry("800x800")
    master1.configure(background="black")
    la=Label(master1, text="Enter Contestant Names:",font="none 50 bold", fg="white", bg="black").pack()
    #I don't know what to put here
    e=Entry(master1, bd=10,width=50).pack()
l=Label(master, text="Tournament Software", font="none 50 bold", bg="black", fg="white").pack()
b=Button(master, text="Start",font="none 50 bold",command = click1).pack(side=LEFT)
b1=Button(master, text="Quit",font="none 55 bold",command = end).pack(side=RIGHT)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You can have only 1 `Tk()` instance in a program. If that `Tk()` is terminated, it normally means termination of the entire program. You can pack a new Entry widget to master and call `update()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code generates a new entry widget each time Enter is pressed:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entryList = list()

def enter_event(event):
    entryList.append(tk.Entry(root))

    entryList[-1].pack()

root.bind("<Return>", enter_event)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Reti43 Ah yes, nice! Thanks! I'll update the answer to remove `lastIndex = len(entryList) - 1` and replace `entryList[lastIndex].pack()` with `entryList[-1].pack()` as it's much simpler.